# WCF Rest API to Upload Images

Tags: c#, wcf, cordova, rest, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to implement a WCF Rest service method to upload images/ files from mobile. Primary requirement is method should be able to get some related information (Id & etc) with the image uploading.

I found below example from this URL. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/tree/master/demo/C%23

Could someone help me to convert the below method to a WCF Rest Service POST Method

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            var userName = context.Request.Form["name"];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];

                string fname = context.Server.MapPath("Uploads\\" + userName.ToUpper() + "\\" + file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("File/s uploaded successfully!");
    }
```

Expected method signature:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/UploadPictures/{id}")]
    bool UploadPictures(string id);
```